Filament Action Modal Close
How to deal with actions that redirect to a Laravel Controller for pdf download, but modal does not close because of the redirect, how to implement something that closes modal.
Forms\Components\Section::make('Accessories')
                    ->schema([
                        Forms\Components\Actions::make([
                                Action::make('car')
                                    ->form(static::getAdsAccessories())
                                    ->action(function (array $data, Action $action){
                                        return redirect()->route('test.index')->with(['data' => $data]);
                                    })
                            ])
                    ]),


did you find any solution?

Actually no!, I left the download button outside modal.

have you tried ->openUrlInNewTab()->url(fn(array $data) => route('test.index')->with(['data' => $data])) instead of ->action( ... )?
